# The site on the localhost does not open via Selenium Webdriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

The site on localhost is opened if I go to it manually.
This code works:

```
driver.get("https://www.example.com/")
```

This code does not work:

```
driver.get("http://localhost/example.com")
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the site only support `https://`?

Comment: Are you actually running an http server on the same machine from which you execute `driver.get("http://localhost/example.com")`? And does your http server on local host have a page example in the .com domain?